# Prove that $``ff^{-1}(x)$ $=$ $x$ $=$ $f^{-1}f(x)"$ $\implies$ $``$the graph of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are reflections of each other in the line $y = x"$.

Tags: functions, inverse-function, reflection

According to the Cambridge International AS & A Level Pure Mathematics $1$ book $(2019$ edition, page $48)$,

> The graph of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are reflections of each other in the line $y = x$. 
> This is because $ff^{-1}(x)=x=f^{-1}f(x)$.
> When a function $f$ is self-inverse, the graph of $f$ will be symmetrical about the line $y=x$.

But how does $``ff^{-1}(x)$ $=$ $x$ $=$ $f^{-1}f(x)"$ imply $``$the graph of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are reflections of each other in the line $y = x"$? Can someone prove it?

Answer (score 0):

The reflection of the point $(\hat x, \hat y)$ in the line $y=x$ is $(\hat y, \hat x)$

So you simply show that for each $\hat x \in \mathcal D(f), \hat y \in \mathcal R(f)$, we have: $$f(\hat x)=\hat y\iff f^{-1}(\hat y)=\hat x$$

Can you show this?

Comment: Yes, I can: $f(\hat x)=\hat y$ $\implies$ $f^{-1}(\hat y)=\hat x$ by the definition of the inverse function of a function. And by the same reason, $f^{-1}(\hat y)=\hat x$ $\implies$ $f(\hat x)=\hat y$. Hence, $f(\hat x)=\hat y\iff f^{-1}(\hat y)=\hat x$.

But how does it prove our original statement?